# Динамическое выделение памяти. Что не удаляется самостоятельно?

Tags: c++, valgrind

Есть код:

```
#include "dparser.hpp"

namespace tools {

string parseToString(const char* _fileName, const char* _needBlockName) {
   ifstream file(_fileName);

   if (!file.is_open()) {
      printf("Parser-Error-E001: Could not open file!\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   char          bufferString[MAX_STR_LEN];
   string        finalString;
   register bool blockIsFind =  false;

   while (file.getline(bufferString, MAX_STR_LEN)) {
      if (!blockIsFind) {
         if (!strcmp(bufferString, _needBlockName)) {
            blockIsFind = true;
         }

         continue;
      }

      if (bufferString[0] == '#') {
         continue;
      }

      if (!bufferString[0]) {
         break;
      }

      finalString += bufferString;
      finalString.push_back('\n');

   } // end while

   file.close();

   if (!finalString.size()) {
      printf("GameTextData-Parser-Error-E002: Block not found!\n");
      exit(2);
   }


   finalString.erase(remove(finalString.begin(), finalString.end(), '"'), finalString.end());
   finalString.pop_back();

   string::size_type charPosition = 0;

   while ((charPosition = finalString.find( "''", charPosition)) != string::npos) {
      finalString.replace(charPosition, 2, 1, '"');
      ++charPosition;
   }

   return finalString;
}

void parseAndPrint(const char* _fileName, const char* _needBlockName) {
   string finalString = parseToString(_fileName, _needBlockName);
   printf("%s\n", finalString.c_str());
}

} // end of 'namespace tools'

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
   tools::parseAndPrint(argv[1], argv[2]);
   return 0;
}
```

При проверке `Valgrind'ом` пишет:

```
==11211== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11211==     in use at exit: 18,944 bytes in 1 blocks
==11211==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 27,511 bytes allocated
...
...
==11211== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11211== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Как видите, `4 allocs и 3 frees`, на сколько я знаю, так быть не должно. Что сдесь не удаляется и как правильно это что-то удалить? А также еще один вопрос: локальные переменные функций `parseToString` и `parseAndPrint` удаляться, после завершения работы своих функций или нет?

### UPD

Код `dparser.hpp`:

```
#ifndef _DPARSER_HPP_
#define _DPARSER_HPP_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 151

using std::string;
using std::replace;
using std::ifstream;

namespace tools {
    string parseToString(const char *data_file_name, const char *need_block_name);
    void   parseAndPrint(const char *data_file_name, const char *need_block_name);
}

#endif // _DPARSER_HPP_
```

### UPD

Данные, которые читаю в цикле (`data.gtd`):

```
[help]
"This is ''help''!"

[lph]
"Hahahhahah"

[main]
"This is main"
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что проблемы с памятью имеют место в этой функции? И что означает это предложение if (!bufferString, _needBlockName) {? Какой его смысл?

Comment: Может быть вы имели в виду if ( !strcmp( bufferString, _needBlockName ) ) вместо if (!bufferString, _needBlockName) {?

Comment: Программа завершилась нормально или с диагностикой `"GameTextData-Parser-Error-E002: Block not found!\n"`?

Comment: Хм, не пойму, почему написано `if (!bufferString, _needBlockName)!`, должно быть `if (!strcmp(bufferString, _needBlockName))`. Сейчас исправлю, спасибо за внимательность!

Comment: @avp нормально.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: "Почему вы решили, что проблемы с памятью имеют место в этой функции?". Потому, что в программе все 2 функции, несчитая `main` и библиотечных.

Comment: @Eanmos Не должно ли это предложение      if (!strlen(bufferString)) {
         break;
      }
находиться перед предложением finalString += (const char*) bufferString;
 которое проще было бы записать как finalString +=  bufferString; ?

Comment: @Eanmos также вместо if (!strlen(bufferString)) { break; }  было бы проще записать if (!bufferString[0]) { break; }

Comment: @Eanmos  Эта функция не выделяет никакой памяти помимо памяти, выделяемой объектами класса std::string.

Comment: @Eanmos Мне любопытно, это вы на работе такой код пишите?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, местоположение проверки на нулевую длину строки ни чего не меняет, но Ваше местоположение лучше, спасибо. Спасибо также за совет со сложением строк, учту на будущее.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, " Эта функция ...", что за функция?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, не на работе. Просто учусь.

Comment: @Eanmos  "Эта функция" - это функция, текст которой вы привели в своем вопросе. Другой функции я не вижу.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, в коде 3 функции, включая `main`.

Comment: Автор, а киньте сюда же файл с данными и dparser.hpp. Скомпилю и посмотрю на компе, а то "всухую" что-то не вижу утечки.

Comment: @Eanmos Я думаю, что проблема связана с вызовом функции exit(). То есть память, выделенная для строки finalString не удаляется при вызове exit.

Comment: @avp, добавил содержимое файла.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, вызов `exit()` не происходил во время выполнения программы.

Comment: А данные, которые читаете в цикле?

Comment: У меня для всех случаев без ошибок (то-то в сухую тоже ничего не нашел). Только у меня Valgrind пишет -- 2 alloc, 2 free (1 для file, другой string, более ничего, файл imho на atexit() посажен, поэтому все подчищается) / **Вы уверены, что запускаете именно этот код?**

Comment: @Eanmos: А попробуйте _убрать_ вызов вашей функции и запустить под valgrind — будет потерянная память или нет?

Comment: Компилирую так: `g++-5 -g -std=c++11 dparser.cpp -o dparser`, запускаю `valgrind`:  `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./dparser data.gtd [help]`

Comment: Если вызвать только `main()`, то: `1 allocs, 0 frees`

Comment: `g++ c.cpp -std=c++11
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ --version
g++.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
.......
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ valgrind ./a.out data.gdt '[help]'
......  ==4406==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4406==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 8,867 bytes allocated
==4406== 
==4406== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible`  вот, все работает `avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$`

Comment: В предыдущем комментарии показано **что все работает без утечек** (идиотская система в которой комменты нельзя форматировать)

Comment: `eanmos@core:~/.projects/Engine/tools$ valgrind ./a.out data.gtd '[help]'  
                                                                                                 ==11832== Memcheck, a memory error detector

==11832== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11832== Command: ./a.out data.gtd [help]
==11832== 
This is "help"!
==11832== 
==11832== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11832==     in use at exit: 18,944 bytes in 1 blocks
==11832==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 27,511 bytes allocated
==11832== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)`

Comment: `Linux core 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:01 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Попробовал еще раз с Вашими ключами `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./a.out data.gdt '[help]'` **Все ОК (4 alloc 4 free)** `valgrind --version
valgrind-3.10.0.SVN`  Что тут сказать, кроме *"лучшее враг хорошего"* (у Вас все версии **новее**). Кстати, у меня Valgrind с многопроцессными программами часто просто падает, что не добавляет уверенности в этом инструменте...

Comment: `COLLECT_GCC=g++-5
...                                                                                                                 gcc version 5.1.1 20150504 (Ubuntu 5.1.1-4ubuntu12)`

Comment: avp, т.е это из-за того, что, у меня `Valgrind` новее? `valgrind-3.10.1`

Comment: Ладно, пустое это занятие искать черных кошек в темной комнате (а может их и нет?). На  мой взгляд у Вас утечек нет. Локальные переменные удаляются. На память,  неосвобожденную при exit() в \*nix можете с чистым сердцем забить.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за столь долгое _детективное расследование_!

Comment: И Вам успехов!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря расследованию **avp** и **Vlad from Moscow**, я понял, что локальные переменные после работы функций удаляются и в программе нет утечки памяти - все из-за расхождений в версиях `Valgrind`.